# Likes report on third-party YouTube videos

Tags: youtube-api, report

I'm creating a website for users to post their videos on a particular topic. The videos will be processed with an intermediate server and then uploaded to each user's YouTube channel. However, I would like to know if the YouTube API, lets you know the number of likes you get each of these videos on YouTube.

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Did you look over the documentation for the API?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

This is where to look. Please invest some effort of your own before asking on SO. Your question is easily solvable by using a search engine.

If you don't yet know how the YouTube API works, inform yourself first. Once you do know and were able to try something out, but are stuck, I encourage you to ask another question with your particular problem (after researching, of course).